# What's the right way to use require.js with web-workers?

Tags: javascript, three.js, requirejs, web-worker

Currently, I'm working on porting an existing web app to `require.js`. Most things seem to work, but the functionality that uses web-workers. For example, I had a worker, defined in a separate js file `MeshLoader.js`, that loads a 3D model from an STL file:

```
importScripts('../lib/three.min.js', '../lib/STLLoader.js');

onmessage = function(e) {
    var blob = e.data;
    var reader = new FileReaderSync();
    readContents(reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob));
};

function readContents(contents) {
    try {
        var geometry = new THREE.STLLoader().parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
        // error handling
    }

    var attributes = {};
    // parsing the file is going on here
    // ...

    postMessage({
            status: 'completed',
            attributes: attributes,
    });
}
```

A small remark: `STLLoader.js` module is a `three.js` plugin that defines `STLLoader` object and adds it to `THREE` namespace. This is how I rewrote it with `require.js`:

```
importScripts('../lib/require.min.js');

require({
    baseUrl: '../lib'
}, [
    'require', 'three.min', 'stlloader'
],
function(require, THREE, STLLoader) {
    onmessage = function(e) {
        var blob = e.data;
        var reader = new FileReaderSync();
        readContents(reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob));
    };

    function readContents(contents) {
        try {
            var geometry = new THREE.STLLoader().parse(contents);
        } catch (e) {
            // error handling
        }

        var attributes = {};
        // same code as in the initial version
        // ...

        postMessage({
            status: 'completed',
            attributes: attributes,
        });
    }

    return onmessage;
});
```

The worker is called the following way:

```
var worker = new Worker('js/workers/MeshLoader.js');
worker.postMessage(blob);
worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    if (event.data.status == 'completed') {
        // ...
    } else if (event.data.status == 'failed') {
       // ...
    } else if (event.data.status == 'working') {
       // ...
    }
};
```

So, the problem is it seems the worker isn't called at all. Maybe I need to declare it as a module in `requirejs.config()` section and then add the module as a dependency to other modules calling this worker?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, redundant debug info is missing. I gave you general answer in my reply, which reliably solves the problem (works here for example: http://darker.github.io/asteroids/demo-simple-bounce/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use it like this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yojaar80/2/)):

```
importScripts("require.js");
requirejs.config({
    //Lib path
    baseUrl: '.',
    // Some specific paths or alternative CDN's
    paths: {
        "socket.io": [
            "//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7",
            "socket.io.backup"]
    },
    waitSeconds: 20
});


requirejs(["LibName"], (TheLibrary) = > {
  // code after all is loaded
  self.onmessage = (msg)=>{
    // do stuff
    TheLibrary.doStuff(msg.data);
  }
  // I tend to dispatch some message here
  self.postMessage("worker_loaded");
}
```

Note that it is **only after you receive `"worker_loaded"`** that you can post messages to the worker, because only then the message will be accepted. Before, the `onmessage` callback is not yet estabilished. So your main code should look:

```
var worker = new Worker("myworker.js");
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  if(e.data=="worker_loaded") { 
    // Tell worker to do some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: If you let me know what exactly is missing, I'll update my question. "redundant debug info" is quite vague thing. However, I see that you're using require.js with your workers differently:

1. you have a `config` section in a file with a worker;

2. you call `requirejs` rather than `require` to initialize the worker.

I'll try to do the same thing with one of my workers.

Comment: I think it's not significant difference - you just passed the config into the `require` call. Rendundant info is info I need to diagnose your problem and test it. I'm not going to ask you thousand questions in comments - sorry I've grown bitter of asking tons of comments to clarify questions. Here's what's the best you can do: http://sscce.org/ In my experience, 70% cases I find solution while making sscce once I remove obscurity from my code.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to isolate the worker, and see if I get smth new.

Comment: Thanks!
I managed to fix the issue after I had a look into your project. The main problem was that I started sending messages to worker right after it had been constructed. It used to work without require.js where worker initialization was synchronous, but it's not the case now. So, I added sending an additional message from worker to report its "ready" state to the main thread that in turn, starts sending messages.

Comment: I guess I should've emphasized that that's why the message is sent in my example. Good job on figurig it out and good luck with the project :)